# How to setup directory trees with puppet?

Tags: puppet

I have several directories and for each I want to set up the same subdirs with puppet.

This obviously doesn't work:

```
$inst = ['/i1', '/i2', '/i3']
$subdirs = ['subdir1', 'subdir2']

file {"${inst}/${subdirs}":
      ensure=>directory,
      recurse=>true,
      purge=>true,
      force=>true,
      owner=>$username,
      group=>$group,
      source=>"puppet:///modules/mymodule/subdirtemplates/${subdirs}/",
      mode=>'644';
}
```

There's no way to concatenate each member of the first array with each member of the second array.

In any normal programming language, you'd use two for loops, or some builtin mapping function or something, but in puppet? Do I have to migrate to the new Ruby DSL?

Answer (score 1):

hmm. I solved it thus:

```
$inst = ['/i1', '/i2', '/i3']
#$subdirs = ['subdir1', 'subdir2']

file {$inst:
  ensure=>directory,
  recurse=>true,
  purge=>true,
  force=>true,
  owner=>$username,
  group=>$group,
  source=>"puppet:///modules/mymodule/subdirtemplates/",
  mode=>'644';
}
```

I made sure that subdirtemplates contained all directories I wanted to be in each instance. It worked for me but maybe someone still has a nicer answer for setting up directory trees in cases where you don't have a template tree.